# In window's 7 PC the downloaded size is 0 kb by using "microsoft.xmlhttp" method?

Tags: vb6

I have struggling with this issue, In my application i have using "microsoft.xmlhttp" by using text Stream method to write the XML from server it works fine in all pc's but one of the customers PC is wont working (ie) the downloaded xml size is 0kb i have tried to overcome the issue but it wont works for me. Please help me to solve the issue.

Below is the method am following

```
    Set http = CreateObject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
        http.Open "POST", API_link, False
        http.Send
        updatedQuery = Trim(http.responseText)
```

for writing the xml

```
   Set fsoStream = fso.OpenTextFile("filepath", ForAppending, True)
        fsoStream.WriteLine updatedQuery
        Set fsoStream = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: What fails? updatedQuery gets no value or it gets data which is not written to file?